# Use library cookbook inside resources

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to   learn library cookbook and wrote one test library cookbook named nol. Inside nol/libraries/nol_helper.rb I have below code

```
module Nol
  module Helper

    include Chef::Mixin::ShellOut

    def has_bacon?
      cmd = shell_out!('getent passwd bacon', {:returns => [0,2]})
      cmd.stderr.empty? && (cmd.stdout =~ /^bacon/)
    end
  end
end
```

In second cookbook I am trying to include it in default.rb recipe as

```
class Chef::Resource::User
        include Nol::Helper
end

user 'noi' do
    action :create
    only_if { has_balcon? }
end
```

But chef keeps on giving below error

```
 ================================================================================
    Error executing action `create` on resource 'user[noi]'
    ================================================================================

    NoMethodError
    -------------
    undefined method `has_balcon?' for Chef::Resource::User
```

Thanks

Comment: And that's not just because you made a type and check `has_baLcon`?

Answer (score 4):

So two things, one you have a simple typo in there, but more importantly it is really not recommended to monkeypatch core Chef classes.

You can accomplish something similar without patching by using a module method instead:

```
module Nol
  def self.has_bacon
    # As before ....
  end
end

user 'noi' do
  only_if { Nol.has_bacon? }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to add this method to user resource, you should extend provider `::Chef::Provider::User.send(:include, Nol::Helper)`